# How to narrow the area between buttons on Helium theme sidebar?

Tags: customization, themes, widgets, sidebar

I have WordPress based [site](https://www.kidum-yeholot.com).
I used [Helium theme](https://smthemes.com/helium/) and added a sidebar.
On this sidebar, I added a few buttons from [SiteOrigin widgets plugin](https://siteorigin.com/widgets-bundle/).

The buttons are being spaced between them automatically, and I would like to narrow this spacing between them. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS code.

```
.sidebar .widget {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Keep in mind currently it has 80px, so change it for what looks best for you.

In case you don't know how to add CSS, [check this out](https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/).

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it helped.

Comment: of course - but I can do it only in 2 minutes. Don't worry... If you could also assist me to understand why does the two tittles in the home page are also spaced out too much, and how to keep them closer I'll be great-full. Thanks!

Comment: It's a different question, but ok; h3 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h4 {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

Comment: This is great. But how come the spacing is so wide. I'll be happy to learn...

Comment: I don't get your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81342/discussion-between-dushkin-and-castiblanco).